# Elasticsearch: REST API works but the Java counterpart doesn't

Tags: elasticsearch

I have one document in Elastic Search:

```
{
   "accountGroupId":1000,
   "name":"Elastic Burgers",
   "capacity":33,
   "startTime":1391604480000,
   "address":{
      "streetName":"Rua Carlos Petit",
      "streetNumber":"111",
      "complement":"",
      "neighborhood":"Vila Mariana",
      "city":"São Paulo",
      "state":"SP",
      "country":"Brasil",
      "zip":"04110000",
      "position":{
         "latitude":-23.5845048,
         "longitude":-46.6358975
      },
      "accountGroupId":1000,
      "status":[

      ],
      "id":1000,
      "createTime":1391010548111,
      "updateTime":1391010548111
   },
   "flyerUrl":"/assets/images/placeholder-merchant.png",
   "backgroundImageUrl":"/assets/images/placeholder-merchant.png",
   "onSaleStartTime":1391604480000,
   "onSaleEndTime":1392990480000,
   "description":"Lorem Ipsum",
   "eventCategoryId":1000,
   "deleted":false,
   "installmentId":100,
   "feeId":101,
   "restricted":false,
   "venueAccountGroupId":15,
   "updateTime":1391691790113,
   "createTime":1391691790113,
   "id":1002,
   "venue":"Acme, Inc.",
   "category":"Festa Faculdade"
}
```

This REST query returns the document:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/paguemob/events/_search' -d '{
    "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
            "query" : "festa de faculdade",
            "fields" : ["name", "address.city", "venue", "category", "description"]
        }    
    }
}'
```

But if I run the equivalent query via the Java API, the result is empty:

```
client
  .prepareSearch(index)
  .setQuery(multiMatchQuery("festa de faculdade", "name", "address.city", "venue", "category", "description"))
  .setSize(200)
  .execute()
  .actionGet()
  .getHits
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at some of the [ES test code](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/f0774eb5d11ea1911e6e5a8722c0ebb073e54ca0/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/search/query/MultiMatchQueryTests.java#L128) I see that in addition to the `multiMatchQuery` itself they also set OR as the operator (I would assume that is the default) and `useDisMax` to `false`, and set the `type`.

```
   searchResponse = client().prepareSearch("test")
   .setQuery(multiMatchQuery("marvel hero captain america", "full_name", "first_name", "last_name", "category")
   .operator(MatchQueryBuilder.Operator.OR).useDisMax(false).type(type)).get();
```

I wonder if one of those is the trick?

Also, your example may not show it but are you accessing the hit results array in Java correctly?

```
searchResponse.getHits().hits()[0]
```

Comment: The `OR` operator is the default one, as for the dismax that affects the way the scores are computed, but it doesn't seem to be the reason why the doc is not returned.

Answer (score 0):

I spotted the error: I had not set the type for the search. So, adding a `.setTypes("events")` to the call did the trick.

Comment: Weird, do you have other types under the same index?